# Execute code on first emission of subscription while still being able to execute multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to execute some code on first emission:

```
mySubscription
.pipe(
filter(res => res.loaded),
SomeRxjsOperator(res => //code to happen once))
.subscribe(res => {//code to happen on each emission});
```

I know I can subscribe twice and use take(1), looking for a different solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try taking advantage of the index property in `concatMap`:

```
mySubscription.pipe(
  concatMap((value, index) => index === 0 ? of(value).pipe(
     tap(value => console.log(`will only be done once: ${value}`))
    ) : of(value)
  )
).subscribe(value => console.log(`subscription here: ${value}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using concatmap can slow down execution here unintentionally.

I would just use mergeMap as it subscribes immediately to the values when they come in.
Also, the more "rxjs way" is using iif.

```js
import { of, iif } from "rxjs";
import { map, mergeMap, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

const source = of("World", "Hello").pipe(
  mergeMap((v, i) =>
    iif(
      () => i === 0,
      of(v).pipe(tap(() => console.log("Only once", v))),
      of(v)
    )
  )
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an easier way with just `map()`:

```
source$
  .pipe(
    map((val, index) => [val, index]),
  )
  .subscribe(([val, index]) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      //code to happen once
    }
    //code to happen on each emission
  });
```